# How to clean data from ruby

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I'm trynna get the text-only but I'm stuck and confused.

"Cars & Minivan\n    \t\t\t\t\t\n    \t\t\t\t\t\n    \t\t\t\t\t\tTrucks\n    \t\t\t\t\t\n    \t\t\t\t\t\n    \t\t\t\t\t\tCrossovers & SUVs\n    \t\t\t\t\t\n    \t\t\t\t\t\n    \t\t\t\t\t\tHybrids & Fuel Cell\n    \t\t\t\t\t\n\n    \t\t\t\t\n    \t\t\t\t\tUpcoming Vehicles"

Comment: Whenever you give an example it is helpful to show the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If `str` is your string perhaps you want simply

```
str.delete("\n\t")
  #=> "Cars & Minivan  Trucks  Crossovers & SUVs  Hybrids & Fuel Cell  Upcoming Vehicles"
```

[See it](https://repl.it/@CarySwoveland/OrneryPotableVariety)

Note that [String#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-delete) does not modify `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` is the newline character (it represents pressing enter to get a new line) and the `\t` is a tab character. You can split your string on these characters to get rid of them (assuming your string is `s`): `s.split(/\n|\t/)`. The thing passed in to split is called a **regular expression**.

This will leave you with a lot of empty strings and spaces in your list. So probably what you want to work with is `cars = s.split(/\n|\t/).select {|c| c.length > 1}`